# Different Ways to create an effective Ci pipeline for sonarqube analysis

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Can some one help me how to configure a best CI pipeline for analyzing source code (JAVA) using Sonarqube?  In my mind I have a Pipeline like `SCM-->Jenkins --->maven build-->sonarqube analysis`.

Is this is a best practice? or can we skip maven build and just do sonarqube analysis `SCM-->Jenkins-->sonarqube analysis`. Is there any other CI pipelines which is a best practice for an organization who are looking  mainly for code analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about a Maven build, then I know we're dealing with Java. In which case, you *must* build before the analysis; much of the analysis relies on byte code for depth and accuracy. If byte code is not available to the SonarJava analyzer you end up with a lot of false negatives.

Specifically, you'll get the same measurements of coverage, duplications, ... with or without byte code. But without byte code, SonarJava looses the ability to, for instance, look at the super class and understand which methods are missing the `@Override` annotation.

**Update**: From SonarJava version 4.12 binary files are required. (See [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava) for more details.)

Comment: "much of the analysis relies on byte code for depth and accuracy" can you please explain this a bit more..Thanks @G.Ann

Comment: See my expansion @pandey